# Rewriting a try catch in Java to Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, try-catch, invoke, arrow-functions

Thinking of rewriting java try catch to Kotlin.
 In case of an error, just need to log a status. 
Is using Arrow with kotlin an overkill ?

sample implementation in Kotlin/Arrow:

```
fun some_method(): <SomeReturnType>{
Try.invoke {
           //code which will return SomeReturnType
        }.getOrElse { throwable ->
            when (throwable) {
                is RuntimeException -> {
            //  do something
                }
                is SomeOtherEception -> {
            //  do something
                }
                else -> {do something}
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you work with a custom set of exceptions that just log a status?

Comment: Well similar think can be implemented only with kotlin stdlib using `runCatching`. Although Arrow is great library, including it just and solely because of this `Try` pattern is overkill.

Comment: The way it's written doesn't add any value. A functional Try would be useful for combining operations, or moving the error handling into the calling method (e.g. return `Try<SomeReturnType>`).